# openCV installation / library problems

Tags: opencv

I have a Dell XPS M1530 running windows 7. I installed virtual box and created an ubuntu 12.04 installation. I then installed openCV as described [here](http://karytech.blogspot.com/2012/05/opencv-24-on-ubuntu-1204.html). Which seems very similar to the directions [here](http://linuxconfig.org/introduction-to-computer-vision-with-opencv-on-linux#4-opencv-examples), but when I try to run g++ on the test program image-conversion.c as described in the second link, I get the following output:

```
jonathan@jonathan-VirtualBox:~/test$ g++ `pkg-config opencv --cflags --libs` image-conversion.c -o image-conversion
/tmp/ccoPBxUv.o: In function `main':
image-conversion.c:(.text+0x1d): undefined reference to `cvLoadImage'
image-conversion.c:(.text+0x41): undefined reference to `cvSaveImage'
image-conversion.c:(.text+0x4d): undefined reference to `cvReleaseImage'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

However, when I use the test program provided by the first link, everything works perfectly. So my question is, what am I not understanding about the installation process or perhaps in the compilation process that is making the examples not work in the second link.

Answer (score 1):

The errors appear to be linking errors, my guess is g++ isn't finding the library. You might try adding the path to libopencv.so to LD_LIBRARY_PATH. Also make sure the version of opencv matches the example. Those three functions are the older c style interface. Also you could run "pkg-config opencv --cflags --libs" in the command line. This will expand it and tell you where it is looking for these things, then you can grep around and see if things match. Sometimes you need #include opencv2/highgui.hpp or some such thing. Also "g++ -v" helps sometimes. Sorry I couldn't just give you a straight answer, Good Luck.